# Wordpress functions.php cannot be saved when using combination of not admin selector and redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having this strange issue to save functions.php in the Wordpress backend editor.

```
/* This saves okay */
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_non_admin_coming_soon_page' );
function redirect_non_admin_coming_soon_page()
{
    if(is_admin()){
        wp_safe_redirect('https://www.mysite.nl/coming-soon'); 
        exit;
    }
}

/* This also saves okay */
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_non_admin_coming_soon_page' );
function redirect_non_admin_coming_soon_page()
{
    if(!is_admin()){
        //wp_safe_redirect('https://www.mysite.nl/coming-soon'); 
        exit;
    }
}

/* But this fails to save*/
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_non_admin_coming_soon_page' );
function redirect_non_admin_coming_soon_page()
{
    if(!is_admin()){
        wp_safe_redirect('https://www.mysite.nl/coming-soon'); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

That last one gives the error message: "Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change by some other means, such as by using SFTP."

Google has not helped me so far, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I still have this issue and it's pretty quiet here....someone any clues on what I do wrong in my example?

Comment: Error is coming from file wp-admin/includes/file.php
It exits 2 tests, 1 with :
```$r = wp_remote_get( $url, compact( 'cookies', 'headers', 'timeout', 'sslverify' ) );```
and the other only:
```$r = wp_remote_get( $url, compact( 'cookies', 'headers', 'timeout' ) );```

Just add ```, 'sslverify'``` in the second after time out and you should be able to push your files :)

Comment: @Maxime GUILHEM I see, but there is of course the saying: "Don't hack the core" :) Anyway I see more strange behaviour when using is_admin(). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62176291/session-start-prevents-saving-in-wordpress-editor/62796792#62796792

Comment: Sure it is not recommanded but adding the SSLverify will just just check if the homepage is https, as it is missing it send the check to an http adress which is unsuccess.
This just add more "security" to your code without alterate the back or front. because it tests the home with secure SSL.