# session_start() prevents saving in Wordpress editor

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have the following code in my custom Wordpress plugin:

```
add_action('init', 'wwp_StartSession', 1);

function wwp_StartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
       session_start();
    }
}
```

When I edit this in the Wordpress editor it can be saved. However if I want to save again after more edits I get the following error:

```
Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change by some other means, such as by using SFTP.
```

When I remove the line

```
sesion_start();
```

I am able to save again.

I already Googled for quite a while now and some say that the if(!session_id()) should do the trick, but it seems it doesn't.

Hoping someone has any ideas on this.

Comment: Check if headers are already sent  .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612163/troubleshooting-warning-session-start-cannot-send-session-cache-limiter-h/20601952

Comment: I hooked in to 'init' with high priority. Also if headers were already sent...I would not be able to save it the first time would I?

Comment: I added a check for the headers sent to verify, but still got the error. Can save it once, but not after that.

Comment: if(!session_id()) {
  if(!headers_sent()) {
         session_start();
  }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out :). I found the answer here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/47320

This is now my code:

```
class Session {
    public static function startSession() {
         // This loads variables to $_SESSION for reading
         if(!session_id()) {
            session_start();
            session_write_close(); // Other plugins can restart a session again via session_start()
        }
    }

    public static function endSession() {
        session_destroy ();
    }

    public static function storeData($key, $value) {
        session_start();
    
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    
        session_write_close();
    }
}
```

startSession is hooked to init
endSession is hooked to wp_login and wp_logout
and wherever I need to save data call storeData

Comment: This doesn't work for me, still gives the loop returning to login screen just as though the session_start isn't present.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Maybe you already found a solution? The problem I had occurred when saving a post or page. I am not sure if I completely understand your problem, but you say you return to the login screen. Since my solution hooks up to wp_login and wp_logout, your issue might maybe be due to the fact that a new session is started when you login or logout. (which is actually a good thing to do to prevent session hijacking). Maybe this helps you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi there, yes I did manage tow work it out, it was down to several session_start calls throughout other plugins that were interfering.

Answer (score 0):

It still behaves strange. If I do this:

```
public function startSession() {
    if(!is_admin() && !session_id()) {
        echo 'not session id';
        session_start();
    } 
}
```

Then it does save in the backend....however I don't have my session variables available...even though the echo statement is printed, so session_start() is called.

If I leave out the !is_admin() part I can work with the session....but then I have the backend trouble again.